# How would you the "this" pointer of the base class from a method of a nested class?

Tags: c++, inner-classes, this-pointer

I have a class nested in a base class, like so:

```
class Base {
public:
    void methodB() { std::cout << "method B"; }
    class Nested {
    public:
        void methodA() { methodB(); }
    };
    Nested * member;
};
```

This obviously generates a compiler error:

```
Cannot call member function methodB without object
```

because `methodB` is not declared as static.  This will be ok in main, because methodB will be called by doing `instanceOfBase.member->methodA()`, which will in turn call methodB, but the problem I'm encountering is that I don't know how to access the underlying `this` pointer to `instanceOfBase` from its member object.

Comment: MethodA must have a parameter that refers to an object of the type Base.

Comment: Would that make methodA static?

Comment: Nested classes are "static", in the sense that they are part of the class and not part of each instance. So you have to treat it as if it is a standalone class in this case.

Comment: @user8577930 You can make MethodA static if it does not refer an object of the class Nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object of a nested class isn't inhanently linked to an object of the class it's definition is nested in.  Consider something like this:

```
Base::Nested{}.methodA()
```

What `Base` object would that operate on?

If you have some invariant that objects of `Nested` are always contained in `Base` objects, then you have to maintain that link.  For example, you could pass your `Base` object's `this` pointer to the `Nested` object's constructor in `Base`'s constructor:

```
class Base {
public:
    class Nested {
    public:
        Nested(Base* owner) : owner{owner} {}
        void methodA() { owner->methodB(); }
        Base* owner;
    };

    Base() : member{this} {}
    void methodB() { std::cout << "method B"; }

    Nested member;
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/883ba37c4af53f04)

Answer (score 2):

> base class ...

"Base" class means something else. You're asking about an *outer* class.

> methodB will be called by doing instanceOfBase.member->methodA(), which will in turn call methodB, but the problem I'm encountering is that I don't know how to access the underlying this pointer to instanceOfBase from its member object.

There is no "underlying" this pointer to instanceOfBase. The structure looks like this:

```
Base ---> Nested
      ^
      |
      pointer
```

"Base" doesn't contain any Nested object, but it does point to one. Nested doesn't contain any "Base" objects, nor does it point to one. Since it is not associated with any "Base", there is no way to access such "Base" object from Nested one.

One solution is to provide a wrapper function in "Base" that passes the instance to the pointed Nested object:

```
class Base {
public:
    // ...
    void methodA() {
        member->methodA(*this);
    }
};
// usage
instanceOfBase.methodA();
```